# Polar protic solvents with melting point between between 0 °C and 25 °C

Tags: physical-chemistry, solvents

Need a solvent for a freezing point depression experiment. Acetic acid is the only one I know of, but it is not ideal due to the low freezing point depression constant. Any suggestions?

Comment: does it have to be polar protic? Benzene is pretty good for FP depression experiments.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb I want a solvent like water, what do u think?

Comment: What do you mean by telling acetic acid is not ideal due to the low freezing point depression constant? $K_f$ of acetic acid is larger than water.

Answer (score 2):

[Followings solvents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_boiling_and_freezing_information_of_solvents) have higher freezing point depression constants than that of water:

$$
\newcommand{\d}[2]{#1.&\hspace{-1em}#2}
\begin{array}{lrr}
\hline
\text{Solvent} & \text{m.p.}/\pu{°C} & K_\mathrm{f}/\pu{°C m-1}  \\
\hline
\text{Water} & 0 & -1.86 \\
\text{Nitrobenzene} & 5.67 & -7.00 \\
\text{Cyclohexane} & 6.54 & -20.2 \\
\text{Acetic acid} & 16.6 & -3.90 \\
tert\text{-Butanol} & 25.82 & -20.2\\
\text{Phenol} & 43.0 & -7.27 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

So far, the best value is that of cyclohexene. Even though its melting point (m.p.) is $\gt \pu{25 ^\circ C},$ I also included phenol, just for curiosity.

Comment: @Buck Thorn: I voted to close under "Openion-based" when it is up. Then I found OP's comment of acetic acid, which is not correct. So I put the data I found as an answer for benefit of readers including OP.

Answer (score 1):

Between $5$°C and $10$°C, you may find the following freezing points : 4-chlorotoluene, nitrobenzene, ethylenediamine, cyclohexane, decanol, formic acid.

Between $10$° and $15$°C, there is : acrylic acid, cyclooctane, dichloracetic acid, dioxane, oleic acid, paraldéhyde, phenylglycol, safrol, p-xylene, m-cresol, ethanolamine.

Between $15$°C and $20$°C, there is : acetophenone, dimethylsulfoxide, glyoxal, lactic acid, methacrylic acid, undecan-1-ol, butane-1,4-diol.

Between $20$° and $25$°C, there is : cyclohexanol, dodecan-1-ol, glycerol, hexadecane, heptadecane

Comment: not all of these are protic though.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb - so pick one that is? Lots of choices there.